# Highmaps displaying a black map without markers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am creating a web app using react JS and this interface will have a pop up that will ask a user to accept permission for the browser to use the user location. Once a user accepts to share location, the app should display a Tanzanian map which will have a marker on the map showing the user location.

Here is how I create the app.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighchartsMap from 'highcharts/modules/map';
import mapData from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json';

HighchartsMap(Highcharts);

const MapChart = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        setLocation({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lon: position.coords.longitude
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const options = {
    chart: {
      map: mapData
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Your Location'
    },
     series: [
      {
        type: "map",
        mapData
      },
{
      type: 'mappoint',
      name: 'Your Location',
      data: location ? [{ lat: location.lat, lon: location.lon }] : []
    }]
  };

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      constructorType={'mapChart'}
    />
  );
};

export default MapChart;
```

Here is how I declare it on app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MapChart from './MapChart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MapChart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, this code works well, I am able to allow browser to use my location and the map is being displayed. My problem is the map is just blank, no marker at all even if after allowing browser to use my location. I have even tried to manually use the longitudes and latitude from the country but still now showing a marker on the map. the map just looks like this
[image]

What am I missing to see this marker on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the [proj4](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) library:

```
import proj4 from "proj4";

const App = () => {
  ...
  const options = {
    chart: {
      map: mapData,
      proj4
    },
    ...
  };
  ...
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-k67guw

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon

**Similar thread:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/123